# Background subtraction in OpenCV

Tags: c++, c, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to implement background subtraction in OpenCV 2.4.10 using mog2. My aim is to segment the hand using background subtraction. Unfortunately, the first frame that is used as foreground appear to be stuck during live capture from the webcam. Here is the code that I used for this simple project

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2\video\video.hpp>
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    Mat frame, mask, gray;

    BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 mog2;

    VideoCapture cap(0);

    if (cap.isOpened()){

        while (true)
        {


            if (cap.read(frame))
            {

                imshow("frame", frame);

                cvtColor(frame, gray, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
                imshow("gray", gray);
                mog2(gray, mask, 0.0);// 0.1 is learning rate
                imshow("Background Subtraction", mask);

                if (waitKey(30) >= 0)
                    break; 
            }
        }

    }
    cap.release();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because your fist happens to be in the very first frame, thus when you move your hand, you get 2 difference images- one from the new position of your palm, and the other from the old location of the fist, now occupied by the actual background behind it.

I would suggest that you shouldn't have your hand in the first frames

Comment: is it possible if I can remove the first frame, I believe the results would be much in that case. @saransh

Comment: Clearly you're taking a live input stream. So you don't need to remove the first frame. Just ensure that are no movable objects in the first few frames.